# Script Bundle and Style Bundle returning 302 Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to add Script and Style Bundling to a fairly old legacy WebForms application.  It works great in debug mode or with **BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false.**

But when I try to enable optimizations as it should be in production, it's not actually creating the bundles so they are returning 302 Not Found errors.

Here's my BundleConfig class

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-validate.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/css_browser_selector.js",
    "~/Scripts/menu.js",
    "~/Scripts/owl.carousel.js",
    "~/Scripts/owl.carousel2.thumbs.js",
    "~/Scripts/general.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
    .Include("~/css/bootstrap.css",
    "~/css/owl.carousel.min.css",
    "~/css/menu.css",
    "~/css/style.css",
    "~/css/responsive.css",
    "~/css/faeaapps_style.css"
    ));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

In the  of the master page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

How they're getting rendered:

```
<script src="/AppName/bundles/js?v=wMldU3OL4sMBTxZpOsGwPTsnbckw_2T1BVZNp1Lopag1"></script>
<link href="/AppName/bundles/css?v=Mdb6m_Rz-GAE4EuPddeqG8CHLfgK1ODoN0WhXZmy09k1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

What happens when the browser tries to load them:

[image: Chrome dev tools showing 302 status response]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I typically minify files myself, but from reading these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#controlling-bundling-and-minification  --- it looks you need to have ````debug=true```` in order to use that ````EnableOptimization```` property

Comment: Setting debug=true or debug=false does not seem to make a difference. When optimization is enabled, either by setting it EnableOptimization = true in debug mode, or by removing the EnableOptimization property and setting debug=false, the problem persists.